# Error updating, packages held

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I'm trying to install nodejs package on my debian (or any other package). And I get this error.

```
pablo@debian:~/Documents/clients/stock$ sudo apt-get install nodejs

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 phonon : Depends: phonon-backend-vlc but it is not going to be installed or
                   phonon-backend
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

How can I solve this? I know there is a lot of post in this page, but none of them seems to fix the problem:

I have already tried with apt-get -f install by I get no problems

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 520 not upgraded.
```

I also check the `/var/log/apt/term.log` file, but no error in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like many of your packages are out of date.

So the package might refer other packages, that don't get updated. Or old packages require versions, that cannot be installed anymore.

Just run following commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install nodejs
```